# What is the purpose of hashing "roles" in Solidity?

Tags: solidity

Granular permissions can be setup in smart contracts by defining specific roles, using [AccessControl.sol](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/access-control). In the OpenZeppelin docs, the following example is given for defining granular permissions to the following `MINTER_ROLE` and `BURNER_ROLE`:

```
...
contract MyToken is ERC20, AccessControl {
   bytes32 public constant MINTER_ROLE = keccak256("MINTER_ROLE");
   bytes32 public constant BURNER_ROLE = keccak256("BURNER_ROLE");
...
```

However, I do not understand why we must hash the name of the role using `keccak256`.

**What is achieved by hashing the name of the role with keccak256?**

Answer (score 2):

It's a gas optimisation feature. Fixed length byte values are cheaper than stings, also having them all of an equal type and defined together saves gas upon deployment.

The hashing returns the `bytes32` value no matter the length of the `string`, so you can have as many roles as you need, identified by strings of variable lengths, but your deployment cost will be lower.

You could also have just `uint8` type of values to specify roles, but this is less error- and overhead-prone.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/api/access#AccessControl) link in the Access Control documentation, roles are referred to **by their bytes32 identifier.**

When you use the `keccak256()` function on a string, it returns a hash of length 32 in bytes, no matter the size of the name of your Role.